# How does Google provide new search suggestions when I'm offline?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

Please see this gif:

[image]

To my knowledge, these are new suggestions. I am offline when doing this.

How does it work?

(using Chrome version 108.0.5359.124)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to show random examples that I don't remember seeing before. But yes it's very possible that it's regurgitating stored suggestions that are saved somewhere in Chrome's file system... It just seems a bit odd that it's suggesting things.

Comment: Caching, its always caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome keeps a database of all past predictions that it ever showed you,
keeping all of them, even the ones that you didn't choose.

This can be viewed via
the `chrome://predictors/` list that keeps track of past guesses of Chrome.
When you start typing in stuff in the navigation bar, Google makes a guess at what you want a based on your browsing history. This predictors list keeps track of what
you typed, what Google guessed, and how accurate the guess was based on whether or not you clicked on it.

The list of past predictions is stored in the file that on Windows
is stored in the file
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PROFILE\Network Action Predictor`.

Future predictions that are not covered by this predictors data, will be based
on your browsing history.

The history is stored for Windows in the folder
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`,
and for the Mac in
`/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`.
It is found inside an SQLite database file named `History` (no file extension),
specifically in an SQL table named `keyword_search_terms`.
For URL predictions, the table is called `urls`.

With this sophisticated mechanism, Chrome is able to suggest predictions
based on its database of past predictions and browsing history,
even when there is no internet connection.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I think this is the best answer I could hope for! I primarily use a Mac, but the file path for Windows users is very interesting. All the best.